# Sending email with PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I've followed a yt-tutorial on how to send an email with PHPMailer. After doing this I ended up with the code below, but it doesn't work for me. I don't get any error messages and I don't get any emails either. What could be the reason to this? Have I missed something? I am using XAMPP as a local server to run my code.

```
require_once ('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = '465';
$mail->isHTML();
$mail->Username = 'sender@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'password';
$mail->SetFrom('no-reply@example.com');
$mail->Subject = 'Hello World';
$mail->Body = 'A test email!';
$mail->AddAddress('reciever@gmail.com');

$mail->Send();
```

Comment: Looks like that tutorial is years out of date, and you have no debug output nor error checking/reporting, so you have no idea what's going on. The examples provided with PHPMailer will give you a far better starting point.

Comment: I recommend you start again using the [gmail](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) and [contact form](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps) examples provided with PHPMailer. If you have trouble, read [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting). If you're new to PHP development, the best thing you can do is learn how to use composer.

Comment: @Synchro So I tried something new and got the error message "SMTP connect() failed". I found this https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Gmail-XOAUTH-smtp-connect()-failed.-Trouble-shooting and wanted to try that out. But I don't get what I'm supposed to do with the lines of code below the sentence **Insert code**. Do you know what to do?

Comment: Ignore that code. It's wrong advice. You can already set options on the OAuth client from outside, you don't need to change any PHPMailer code. Also, that will have nothing to do with the "connect() failed`" error as that will be happening before it gets as far as authentication. Please follow the advice in the guide so that you can see what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Download the php mailer from https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer and use it.
To use it: first you need to create a folder called "phpmailer". And then put the php mailer folder you downloaded in it.
then use this code:

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header('Access-control-Allow-Headers: Authorization,Content-Type ,X-Auth-Token , Origin');
   $username=$_POST["email"];
   $password=$_POST["password"];
   $to=$_POST["to"];
   $subject=$_POST["subject"];
   $body=$_POST["body"];

   // Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
   // These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

   // Load Composer's autoloader
   require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
   require 'phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
   require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';

   // Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
   $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

   try {
    //Server settings
     $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                      // Enable verbose debug output
     $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
     $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                    // Set the SMTP    server    to send through
     $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP      authentication
    $mail->Username   = $username;                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = $password;                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';         // Enable TLS encryption; `  PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

//Recipients
   $mail->setFrom('no-reply@gmail.com',$username);
   $mail->addAddress($to);     // Add a recipient


   // Attachments
   // $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
   // $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

   // Content
   $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
   $mail->Subject = $subject;
   $mail->Body    = $body;
   //$mail->AltBody =;

   $mail->send();

   echo "<script>";
   echo "window.alert('Email was sent')";
   echo "</script>";


  } catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
  }
 ?>
```

Also make sure you turn "less secure app access" on for this to work. Because such codes use existing email to send emails. The easiest way is to use your gmail account.

Comment: You don't have to allow "less secure apps"; google wants you to use XOAUTH2 authentication, which PHPMailer also supports, though it's harder to set up.

Comment: you can choose whatever you want but I am giving a simple solution.

Comment: OK, but in that case you should not advise using user-submitted credentials for authenticating with gmail; that's an open proxy for attacking gmail accounts, and doing the same for to address and body content makes this script an open spam gateway. Simple is good, but vulnerable is bad. the stock gmail example provided with PHPMailer avoids these issues.

Comment: yes you are right but we can create a gmail account just for sending emails from and not using the ones we use to save our progress in games and backups.

Comment: When I did this I got the error message "SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted." I wrote the email and password to my gmail-account that I want to send the email from as username and password, is that wrong?

Comment: no that is not wrong ,that is exactly what you should do. but are you sure you allowed "less secure app access" on your gmail account?? and are you logged in to your account??